# Use Azure DevOps service principal details in Azure Powershell task

Tags: azure-devops

When writing an Azure CLI script in a Azure DevOps pipeline you can get access to the the serviceprincpal id, key and tenantid. Is there a way to get this info in a Azure Powershell task?

Comment: Azure Powershell task doesn't have the feature to access those info directly, so we have to add an Azure Cli task before Azure PS task to pass those values to our own variables, and then share it to following Azure PS task. (`task.setvariable variable xxx`). If you see the `***`, it means the values are correctly passed cause devops only project secret values from displaying in logs...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `addSpnToEnvironment` input which adds service principal id and key of the Azure endpoint you chose to the script's context is one option available only in [Azure ClI Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops), but not [Azure Powershell Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops).

> Is there a way to get this info in a Azure Powershell task?

As an alternative workaround, we can define job-scoped variables in `Azure ClI Task`, check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cpowershell#set-variables-in-scripts).

**Steps to test:**

1.Using latest `Azure CLI task` **2.0-preview** and choose **Powershell** type. Try inline script like this:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SpId;]$env:servicePrincipalId"

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SpKey;]$env:servicePrincipalKey"

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TenantId;]$env:tenantId"

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TestVar;]JustForTest"
```

2.Then add one `Azure Powershell task` after `Azure CLI Task` to test:

```
Write-Host $env:SpId

Write-Host $env:SpKey

Write-Host $env:TenantId

Write-Host $env:TestVar
```

3.Output:

[image]

So if you define the job-scoped variables using `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=xxx]xxx"`(Powershell) or `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=xxx]xxx"`(Batch), you can then use something like `$env:VariableName` to access the info. The `***` in log is because these are secrets projected by Azure Devops, so they're masked.

Comment: Bit of a hack, one which I considered, but I hoped for something better.

Comment: Hi @LoLance,

Thanks for this solution, I am trying to use the variables (as you described above) to login i.e
az login --service-principal --username "$env:SpId" --password "$env:SpKey" --tenant "$env:TenantId"



but it gives error
ERROR: argument --username/-u: expected one argument. I have tried without quote marks as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke a powershell script via Azure CLI task and use the 'addSpnToEnvironment' flag as explained in accepted answer.

```
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: 'Custom ps script'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
        addSpnToEnvironment: true  # Adds DevOps SP details to context
        scriptType: pscore
        scriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/somescript.ps1'
```