# Why does 'az storage file upload-batch' not support '--auth-mode'?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-storage-files

Context: trying to upload files from a YAML pipeline to an Azure storage account's file share. It should use the Azure Connected Service (service principle/app registration in Azure), and not the storage account key or a SAS token. The connected service has (various) contributor rights to the storage account and a reader role to the resource group.

Problem: if I leave out the '--account-name' and '--account-key' (because I don't want to use them), I get the error message: 'You need to provide either an account shared key or SAS token when creating a storage service'.

If I use the variant for blob 'az storage blob upload-batch' I can add the '--auth-mode login' parameter to force the service principle to be used.

Why does the file upload-batch variant not support this '--auth-mode'?

The work-around for this now seems to be: use AzureFileCopy@5 to upload to blob, and then AzureCLI@2 to copy the files from blob to file share within the same storage account.

Comment: how are your running this script? the AzureCLI@2 should take care of authentication (using the service principal) without needing to provide --acount-key or --authmode
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureCLIV2/Readme.md#parameters-of-the-task

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the file upload-batch variant not support the '--auth-mode'?

According to this [MS-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/file?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-file-upload-batch), the `az storage file upload-batch` command does not support the `--auth-mode` parameter because it is designed to use the storage account key or a SAS token for authorization.

I agree with Thomas's comment, **`AzureCLI@2`** task can manage authentication using a service principal.

**yml:**

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'xxxx'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      az storage file upload-batch -s "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/your-local-directory" -d share1/test --account-name venkat0123 2>$null
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
```

**`addSpnToEnvironment: true`** for Accessing service principal details in the script.

**Output:**

```
[
  "https://venkat0123.file.core.windows.net/share1/test/demo.pdf",
  "https://venkat0123.file.core.windows.net/share1/test/demo326.cer",
  "https://venkat0123.file.core.windows.net/share1/test/demo326.cer.thumbprint.txt"
]
```

**Reference:**
[Use Azure DevOps service principal details in Azure Powershell task - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60901921/use-azure-devops-service-principal-details-in-azure-powershell-task) by LoLance.